# What is the name of these software on 2 screen?

Tags: 3d, render

Look at the photo, modelling for new products.

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the interface that would be blender:

https://www.blender.org/

Please note that here is a bender-specific stackexchange site as well:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/